# Update current time date without exploding in memory

Tags: java, date, time

I have written the following Java code:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setTime(new Date());
Date currentDate = null;

while (now.compareTo(stop) < 0 ) {  
    currentDate = new Date();
    now.setTime(currentDate);
}
```

that is meant to track down the time passing while other components (in particular: a Twitter Streaming listener) perform other actions. So, this is not meant to be a simple sleep, since other components are running in the meanwhile: this loop is just meant to keep the machine occupied for a while, until the date indicated by `stop` arrives.

However, by doing this the memory size keeps increasing a lot. I profiled the thing and I saw that this generates a huge amount of `Date` objects in memory.

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a thread and semaphores? `while` loops cause the app to be detected as *non-responsive* when the time is longer than 3-5 seconds, and it looks bad for the user.

Comment: I have never use them. Any pointer to a specific example would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a good start: [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). But if you're too lazy: [A simple example](http://www.cs.nccu.edu.tw/~linw/javadoc/tutorial/java/threads/simple.html)

Comment: Nope, not lazy. Any new learned thing is a good start for improving :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep and check until condition is true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464544/sleep-and-check-until-condition-is-true) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/319485/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum change is to use [`setTimeInMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis-long-) using [`System.currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) rather than `setTime`:

```
while (now.compareTo(stop) < 0 ) {                  // Ugh, busy wait, see below
    now.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

...or actually, just use milliseconds in the first place:

```
long stopAt = stop.getTimeMillis();
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < stopAt) {       // Ugh, busy wait, see below
}
```

**However,** surely with broader context there's a way to avoid busy-waiting at all. Busy-waits are almost never appropriate.

> So, this is not meant to be a simple sleep, since other components are running in the meanwhile: this loop is just meant to keep the machine occupied for a while, until the date indicated by `stop` arrives.

Presumably those components are running on other threads, as your `while` loop is a busy-wait.

That being the case, this thread should sleep — either for a period of time, or until it's woken up by something else.

For instance, you haven't said what `stop` is, but as you're using it with `compareTo` presumably it's a `Calendar`. So it should be possible to get the difference (in milliseconds, via [`getTimeInMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis--)) between `stop` and `now`, and [`sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) rather than busy-waiting:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); // Initializes to "now", no need to do that yourself
long delay = stop.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
if (delay > 0) {
    Thread.sleep(delay);
}
```

Comment: It'd be better if you provided an example to avoid using busy-waiting.

Comment: @arielnmz: Just did. Had to remind myself of `Calendar`'s awful API. :-)