# Hold the main thread execution until another threads are being executed

Tags: java

```
package Pack3;

public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Main Thread Started !!");

                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        System.out.println("Waiting Mode ");
                        this.wait();
                        System.out.println("Main thread exited");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        t.start();

        Thread[] t1 = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            t1[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Executed");
                }
            });

            if (i == 9) {

                synchronized (t1[i]) {
                    t1[i].notifyAll();
                    t1[i].start();
                }

            } else {
                t1[i].start();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output is :

```
Main Thread Started !!
Waiting Mode 
Thread-1Executed
Thread-2Executed
Thread-4Executed
Thread-3Executed
Thread-6Executed
Thread-7Executed
Thread-5Executed
Thread-8Executed
Thread-9Executed
Thread-10Executed
```

But t(Main Thread) is not exited ? Why?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: If you now the number of threads, you could use a `CountDownLatch`, if not you could use a `ExecutorService` of some kind

Comment: *"But t(Main Thread) is not exited ? Why?"* - Because `this.wait()` is never been notified

Comment: I want to wake my main thread(t) again How can I wake up it?

Comment: Something like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456633/wait-main-thread-until-one-of-out-many-threads-signals-in-java/34456666#34456666

Comment: You can set all those threads as non-daemon thread then your program will only exit when all the threads have ended their execution, but this is risky as you might end up in never ending loop if something goes wrong (i.e. in your code if you have bug, not sure from the OS side). You might want to take measures on how to prevent a thread from being existing continuously

Comment: Can you please provide code ?

Comment: Programme definition is "Hold the main thread execution until another threads are being executed"